# iPhone Lite Version Upgrade

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have a lite version of my application.  I want to include a link or something that sends the user to the App Store so they can purchase the full version of my App.

I do not want to do that In App Purchase program though.

Is this allowed, just want to make sure, i'm not seeing anything definitive online.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a link to your full version app in the App Store.  There's nothing wrong with that.  It won't count as an In App purchase, it will count as a regular App Purchase.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't want to get an app rejection